# How do I ignore a GAC reference from Cassini?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, gac, cassini

I have an assembly in the GAC which gets loaded when I'm debugging a web app. However, I've changed that assembly in the web app that I'm debugging but VS2008/Cassini is picking up the one in the GAC.

How do I make VS2008/Cassini use the one that I'm debugging?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the version of the updated assembly and ensure that the assembly reference in the web app fully qualifies the version.